# Crash when loading an enum

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I received a crash log and am a bit puzzled about it.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018e4c20a0 objc_msgSend + 32
1   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192be86b8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _nsis_center:bounds:inEngine:forLayoutGuide:] + 1328 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3674)
2   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192ca003c -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValuesToBoundsOnly:] + 364 (UIView.m:0)
3   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192ca04ac -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 136 (UIView.m:10182)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e77195c __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSArrayHelpers.m:9)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e674fb0 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 416 (NSArrayM_Common.h:390)
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192c9f5e4 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 156 (UIView.m:9953)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192be76fc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 148 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3231)
8   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192ca7090 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 1032 (UIView.m:12082)
9   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192cba17c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140 (UIView.m:17028)
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001952222c0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284 (CALayer.mm:9627)
11  QuartzCore                      0x000000019522843c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480 (CALayer.mm:9501)
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000195233140 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136 (CALayer.mm:2461)
13  QuartzCore                      0x000000019517b884 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304 (CAContextInternal.mm:1992)
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001951a5574 CA::Transaction::commit() + 676 (CATransactionInternal.mm:438)
15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001951a5f68 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92 (CATransactionInternal.mm:888)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e71be68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1758)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e716d54 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416 (CFRunLoop.c:1868)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e717320 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308 (CFRunLoop.c:2910)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e716adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
20  GraphicsServices                0x00000001986b7328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
21  UIKitCore                       0x000000019282463c UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
22  MyAppName                       0x0000000100b96974 main + 68 (Theme+Fonts.swift:14)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018e5a0360 start + 4
```

The Theme+Fonts.swift file is a simple enum

```
enum ThemeFont: String {
    case arialBold = "Arial-BoldMT",
    arialRoundedBold = "Arial Rounded MT Bold", // This is line 14
    …
}
```

How can I investigate further?
It happened on an iPhone 7. I don't have a device but I tested on the Simulator and got nothing.

Comment: Possibly not related to the enum, CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION

Comment: It makes more sense. Jot down a quick answer and I'll accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not caused by the enum code but rather has something to do with the callback here

```
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e71be68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1758)
```